# Mercury Barometer

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, surface-tension

Why Mercury surface is flat instead of convex at 760mm Hg level in Mercury Barometer? refer the image attached. note that At top it is a vacuum

[image]

and surface tension = (pi-po)r/2.

Comment: If the surface is truly flat, then the pressure difference across the interface is zero.

Comment: Your interpretation seems right. for equilibrium position and Young-Laplace principle, the surface will be flat when no force acts on either side. Here, the interface should be flat for any liquid. what is your view?

Comment: The surface won't be flat because there is a natural contact angle that the fluid takes with the wall.

Comment: @Chet Miller Yes indeed, but although very convex at the edges for this reason, the surface won't be hemispherical unless the tube bore is very narrow (say < 2 mm diameter). If wider than this the mercury surface will be more like the top of the yolk of a fried egg, because gravitational effects on the surface will be comparable with surface tension effects. This 'flatenning' will make the convexity more difficult to see than if the surface were hemispherical.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely still convex, you can't see it due to contamination and photo quality. Also large capillary diameter could make it less noticeable.

But indeed surface tension of mercury depend on many parameters - temperature, contamination of mercury, contamination of glass. You can see that glass is severely contaminated by mercury (it has black tint). This being very old barometer - might have significantly lower Mercury surface tension vs freshly distilled Mercury in clean capillary.

More slightly more information you can refer to section 11 in "Mercury manometers and barometers", https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GOVPUB-C13-409eb7129db82afdff65999c7c88f23f/pdf/GOVPUB-C13-409eb7129db82afdff65999c7c88f23f.pdf